# Insert the data by running trigger but after running the condition in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, insert-update

I am trying to insert data in the form of creating trigger. But before inserting the data into the table, I want to run one condition which is

`want to delete the data with some condition`. So I implemented like this below

Once the condition is true then only INSERT otherwise not.

```html
create or replace TRIGGER APP_WFM.TRG_INS_NE_SF_SITE_INSTANCE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SF_NE_DETAILS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

IF

DELETE FROM NE_SITE_INSTANCE
WHERE build_by IN ('RCOM','RJIL','IP1','IP1 COLO')
AND validation_status IS NULL
AND wfm_hoto_flag IS NULL;

THEN

  INSERT INTO NE_SITE_INSTANCE ( 
    rf_siteid,
    sap_id,
    sitename,
    DSUPPLIERBATTERYBANK,
    DUTILITYINSTBATTERYBANK,
    DENDDGDATE,
    DSTARTDGDATE,
    DEMFEND,
    DEMFSTART,
    DQUALITYDATE,
    DRFE1OFFERED,
    DUTILITYINSTODC,
    DSUPPLIERSMPS,
    DUTILITYINSTSMPS,
    DLTOWERPOLEMATERIAL,
    DLNOOFPLATFORM,
    DLNOOFPOLES,
    DLNOOFSECTORS,
    DLBATREDIFIER,
    DLNOOFREDINSMPS,
    FUBATCOMMREPORT,
    FUDGCOMREPORT,
    FUSMPSCOMREPORT,
    DLSHELTER,
    CANDIDATEID,
    CIRCLE,
    CITY_NAME,
    LATITUDE,
    LONGITUDE,
    DLMATERIALSUPPLIER,
    DLBATMODELNAME,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO1,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO2,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO3,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO4,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO5,
    DBATRECTIFIERSRNO6,
    DCBMS,
    DDGALTERNATEMAKE,
    DGALTERNATESRNO,
    DCRANKMAKE,
    DCRANKSRNO,
    DDCENGINEMAKE,
    DDGENGINESRNO,
    DLDGMODELNAME,
    DLEARTHING,
    DLRP1MODELNAME,
    DCENERGYMETEROWNSRNO,
    DLMODELFDPFDMS1_COUNT,
    DLMODELFDPFDMS1,
    DFDPMAKE,
    DLMODELFDPFDMS_COUNT,
    DLMODELFDPFDMS,
    DODCMAKE,
    DLDOCMODELNAME,
    ODCSERIALNO,
    DLGO,
    DSHELTERMAKE,
    DSHELTERSRNO,
    DCONTROLLERADDRESS,
    DSMPSMAKE,
    DLMODELSMPS,
    DPAUIPADDRESS,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO1,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO2,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO3,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO4,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO5,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO6,
    DSMPSSRNO,
    DLLTOWERTYPE,
    DSUPPLIERFDMS,
    DRFE1DECLARED,
    SITE_TYPE,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO7,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO8,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO9,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO10,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO11,
    DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO12,
    ALARM_GATEWAY_MAKE,
    ALARM_GATEWAY_MODEL_NAME,
    ALRM_GTWAY_INTS_DT,
    ALRM_GTWAY_SR_NO,
    ALRM_GTWAY_COMM_DT


  ) VALUES (
    :NEW.rf_siteid,
    :NEW.sap_id,
    :NEW.site_name,
    :NEW.DSUPPLIERBATTERYBANK,
    :NEW.DUTILITYINSTBATTERYBANK,
    :NEW.DENDDGDATE,
    :NEW.DSTARTDGDATE,
    :NEW.DEMFEND,
    :NEW.DEMFSTART,
    :NEW.DQUALITYDATE,
    :NEW.DRFE1OFFERED,
    :NEW.DUTILITYINSTODC,
    :NEW.DSUPPLIERSMPS,
    :NEW.DUTILITYINSTSMPS,
    :NEW.DLTOWERPOLEMATERIAL,
    :NEW.DLNOOFPLATFORM,
    :NEW.DLNOOFPOLES,
    :NEW.DLNOOFSECTORS,
    :NEW.DLBATREDIFIER,
    :NEW.DLNOOFREDINSMPS,
    :NEW.FUBATCOMMREPORT,
    :NEW.FUDGCOMREPORT,
    :NEW.FUSMPSCOMREPORT,
    :NEW.DLSHELTER,
    :NEW.CANDIDATEID,
    :NEW.CIRCLE,
    :NEW.CITY_NAME,
    :NEW.LATITUDE,
    :NEW.LONGITUDE,
    :NEW.DLMATERIALSUPPLIER,
    :NEW.DLBATMODELNAME,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO1,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO2,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO3,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO4,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO5,
    :NEW.DBATRECTIFIERSRNO6,
    :NEW.DCBMS,
    :NEW.DDGALTERNATEMAKE,
    :NEW.DGALTERNATESRNO,
    :NEW.DCRANKMAKE,
    :NEW.DCRANKSRNO,
    :NEW.DDCENGINEMAKE,
    :NEW.DDGENGINESRNO,
    :NEW.DLDGMODELNAME,
    :NEW.DLEARTHING,
    :NEW.DLRP1MODELNAME,
    :NEW.DCENERGYMETEROWNSRNO,
    :NEW.DLMODELFDPFDMS1_COUNT,
    :NEW.DLMODELFDPFDMS1,
    :NEW.DFDPMAKE,
    :NEW.DLMODELFDPFDMS_COUNT,
    :NEW.DLMODELFDPFDMS,
    :NEW.DODCMAKE,
    :NEW.DLDOCMODELNAME,
    :NEW.ODCSERIALNO,
    :NEW.DLGO,
    :NEW.DSHELTERMAKE,
    :NEW.DSHELTERSRNO,
    :NEW.DCONTROLLERADDRESS,
    :NEW.DSMPSMAKE,
    :NEW.DLMODELSMPS,
    :NEW.DPAUIPADDRESS,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO1,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO2,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO3,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO4,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO5,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO6,
    :NEW.DSMPSSRNO,
    :NEW.DLLTOWERTYPE,
    :NEW.DSUPPLIERFDMS,
    :NEW.DRFE1DECLARED,
    :NEW.SITE_TYPE,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO7,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO8,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO9,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO10,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO11,
    :NEW.DSMPSRECTIFIERSRNO12,
    :NEW.ALARM_GATEWAY_MAKE,
    :NEW.ALARM_GATEWAY_MODEL_NAME,
    :NEW.ALRM_GTWAY_INTS_DT,
    :NEW.ALRM_GTWAY_SR_NO,
    :NEW.ALRM_GTWAY_COMM_DT
  );
END;
```

But its giving error as

> Error(8,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DELETE" when expecting one of the following:     ( - + case mod new not null          continue avg count current exists max min prior sql stddev    sum variance execute forall merge time timestamp interval    date       pipe        <an alternat

Comment: What is your `if` statement attempting to do?  Perhaps you want to run the `delete` and check `sql%rowcount` to determine whether rows were removed?  I'd guess that you really want to move the `delete` into a statement-level trigger.  If you insert 1000 rows with a single statement, it seems unlikely that you'd want to run the `delete` 1000 times.

Comment: @JustinCave: Yes, I want to check whether before inserting the data into the `NE_SITE_INSTANCE` table any rows were deleted or not. So what would be the best possible way to implement this ? Pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to check whether the `delete` removed rows before running the `insert`, you'd want something like

```
create or replace TRIGGER APP_WFM.TRG_INS_NE_SF_SITE_INSTANCE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SF_NE_DETAILS 
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  DELETE ...

  IF( sql%rowcount > 0 )
  THEN 
    INSERT ...
  END IF;
END;
```

It's not obvious to me that this makes a whole lot of sense, though.  If you run a SQL statement that inserts 1000 rows into `SF_NE_DETAILS`, you'd run the delete 1000 times (which seems inefficient) and insert only a single row into `NE_SITE_INSTANCE`.  That seems unlikely to be what you really want.  My guess is that you really want a statement-level trigger that does the `delete`

```
create or replace TRIGGER APP_WFM.TRG_INS_NE_SF_SITE_INSTANCE
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON SF_NE_DETAILS 
BEGIN
  DELETE ...
END;
```

and then the row-level trigger that just does the `insert`.  Then in the case that you run an `insert` that inserts 1000 rows, you'd run the delete once and the `insert` 1000 times.

Of course, this assumes that there is a good reason that you need to have two tables that seem to consist of mostly duplicate information.  That would make some sense if `ne_site_instance` was a history table but that doesn't appear to be what's going on here.  Are you sure that you don't really want a view/ materialized view/ something else?

Comment: I totally agree with you Justin, just wanted to frame the logic and you saved it for me. So I am going with your second answer which seems perfect to me

Comment: I cannot have view but a trigger because I want to insert in another table whenever there is data insertion in first table..

Comment: @hud - Like I said, having two tables that appear to duplicate dozens of different data attributes when one isn't a history table seems highly suspect.  It makes sense if one was a history table but it doesn't look like that's what you have here.  So you appear to be violating rule 0 of proper normalization and database design.  Hopefully, you have a really solid reason for doing this that isn't clear from the question.  I'm just pointing out that your code is raising a bunch of red flags.

Comment: can we make it in a view ??

Comment: @hud - It seems like `NE_SITE_INSTANCE` could be a view on `SF_NE_DETAILS`, yes.  But I don't understand what those two tables represent in your system or why you'd want to duplicate a whole bunch of data in those two tables.

Comment: in 2 tables, the main difference is:  in `SF_NE_DETAILS` the data comes from vendor or 3rd party. so we want to replicate those data in our table which is `NE_SITE_INSTANCE`.

Comment: It isn't obvious why that would justify having two tables with the same data in both tables where you are trying to keep the two tables in sync.  If this is part of a data load process and `sf_ne_details` is a staging table, you'd want to move the data to `ne_site_instance` as part of an explicit step in your ETL process not with a trigger on the staging table.  That defeats the whole purpose of a staging table.